# Getting the version level of FreeBSD for a ZFS boot environment that is mounted but not booted

Tags: freebsd, zfs, trueos

`uname -v` gives me the version level of the booted environment.

How can I get the version level of an environment without booting that environment?

In the example below, a boot environment (BE) is mounted at a temporary path by TrueOS Desktop. I can access relevant parts of the file system but I don't know where to seek the required information:

```
$ date ; uname -v
Fri 25 Nov 2016 21:15:19 GMT
FreeBSD 12.0-CURRENT #14 1717ae3(drm-next-4.7): Fri Oct 28 13:49:49 UTC 2016     root@gauntlet:/usr/obj/usr/src/sys/GENERIC 
$ beadm list
BE                              Active Mountpoint                                        Space Created           Nickname
initial                         -      -                                                  5.4G 2016-08-22 11:24  initial
20161005193649_201610142022     -      -                                                  3.1G 2016-10-14 20:22  12.0-CURRENT-up-20161014_204827
20161028134949_201610291803     -      -                                                753.6M 2016-10-29 18:03  12.0-CURRENT-up-20161029_180801
20161028134949_14_201611081710  NR     /                                                 45.4G 2016-11-08 17:10  12.0-CURRENT-up-20161108_171012
12.0-CURRENT-up-20161125_173806 -      -                                                  7.5G 2016-11-25 17:12  12.0-CURRENT-up-20161125_173806
12.0-CURRENT-up-20161125_201510 -      /tmp/BE-12.0-CURRENT-up-20161125_201510.nsZfNFVo   7.4G 2016-11-25 19:49  12.0-CURRENT-up-20161125_201510
$ ls -hl /tmp/BE-12.0-CURRENT-up-20161125_201510.nsZfNFVo
total 215
drwxr-xr-x   2 root  wheel    48B 25 Nov 19:56 bin
drwxr-xr-x  10 root  wheel    60B 25 Nov 20:15 boot
drwxr-xr-x   3 root  wheel     3B 25 Nov 20:02 compat
-r--r--r--   1 root  wheel   6.0K 17 Aug 16:12 COPYRIGHT
dr-xr-xr-x   2 root  wheel     3B 22 Aug 11:31 dev
-rw-------   1 root  wheel   4.0K 25 Nov 19:48 entropy
drwxr-xr-x  30 root  wheel   129B 25 Nov 20:15 etc
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel     9B 22 Aug 11:35 home -> /usr/home
drwxr-xr-x   4 root  wheel    59B 25 Nov 19:56 lib
drwxr-xr-x   4 root  wheel     6B 25 Nov 19:56 libexec
drwxr-xr-x   2 root  wheel     2B 21 Nov 03:14 media
drwxr-xr-x   2 root  wheel     2B  8 Oct 12:21 mnt
drwxr-xr-x   2 root  wheel     2B 22 Aug 12:05 net
drwxr-xr-x   2 root  wheel     2B 22 Aug 11:25 packages
-rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel    21K 25 Nov 20:15 pkg-add.log
dr-xr-xr-x   2 root  wheel     2B 17 Aug 16:12 proc
drwxr-xr-x   2 root  wheel   146B 25 Nov 19:56 rescue
drwxr-xr-x  10 root  wheel    21B 13 Nov 20:13 root
drwxr-xr-x   2 root  wheel   146B 25 Nov 19:56 sbin
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    11B 17 Aug 16:12 sys -> usr/src/sys
drwxr-xr-x   6 root  wheel     8B 25 Nov 20:20 tmp
drwxr-xr-x  17 root  wheel    17B 22 Aug 11:32 usr
drwxr-xr-x  28 root  wheel    30B 25 Nov 20:11 var
$
```

#### Reference

[FreeBSD manual page for beadm(1)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=beadm&sektion=1&manpath=FreeBSD%20Ports)

Comment: Worth noting: <https://forums.freebsd.org/posts/543375>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does `strings /tmp/BE-.../boot/kernel/kernel | egrep ^FreeBSD` solve your issue?

Comment: Thanks; https://gist.github.com/grahamperrin/5404fa1af9409302725f03a2274034e2

Comment: … and `egrep main-c` narrows it down nicely for `13.0-CURRENT`, `13.0-ALPHA1` and so on.